# Returning Interface in Golang

Tags: go, methods, interface

Let say we want to extend `Error()` function on `error` interface. We can simply create a struct derived from string implementing the `Error()` method. For example:

```
type NewUser struct {
    Email           string
    Password        string
}
type ErrMissingField string

func (e ErrMissingField) Error() string {
    return string(e) + " is required"
}

func (u *NewUser) OK() error {
    if len(u.Email) == 0 {
        return ErrMissingField("email")
    }
    if len(u.Password) == 0 {
        return ErrMissingField("password")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Above code will return either `email is required` or `password is required`.

But, if I create my own interface, let say `ResponseError`, like this:

```
type ResponseError interface {
    ErrorMsg() string
}

type CustomErr string

func (c CustomErr) ErrorMsg() string {
    return "[Error] " + string(c)
}
func (u *NewUser) NewOK() ResponseError {
    if len(u.Email) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Email required!")
    }
    if len(u.Password) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Password Required!")
    }
    return nil
}
```

It won't print the method implementation I wrote with `[Error]`. It just prints the string I passed into the struct `Email required!` or `Password Required!`.

How to work on this?

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to print ?

Comment: What is your goal? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I use fmt to print the error msg. My goal is only to customize error interface. Btw, the answer is already covered by nighfury

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using fmt to print, then from https://golang.org/pkg/fmt

4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any)

That's why when you implement **Error** interface, it prints by invoking `Error()` function. If you want custom output for other interface like `ResponseError` implement `String()` method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type NewUser struct {
    Email           string
    Password        string
}

type ResponseError interface {
    ErrMsg()
    String() string
}

type CustomErr string

func (c CustomErr) String() string {
    return "[Error] " + string(c)
}

func (c CustomErr) ErrMsg() {}

func (u *NewUser) NewOK() ResponseError {
    if len(u.Email) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Email required!")
    }
    if len(u.Password) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Password Required!")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    u := &NewUser{}
    fmt.Println(u.NewOK())
}
```

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/khAAtLodEND

Answer (score 1):

Go treats `type`s that implement `error` differently when printing. Your interface `ResponseError` does **not** implement `error` through adding `Error() string`.

To visualize what I'm talking about see the following example using `error` interface:

```
type NewUser struct {
    Email    string
    Password string
}

type ResponseError interface {
    error
    ErrorMsg() string
}

type CustomErr string

func (c CustomErr) ErrorMsg() string {
    return "[Error] " + string(c)
}

func (c CustomErr) Error() string {
    return c.ErrorMsg()
}

func (u *NewUser) NewOK() ResponseError {
    if len(u.Email) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Email required!")
    }
    if len(u.Password) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Password Required!")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    user := NewUser{}
    fmt.Printf("Using %%s: %s\n", user.NewOK())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%v: %v\n", user.NewOK())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%v and call function ErrorMsg: %v\n", user.NewOK().ErrorMsg())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%s and call function ErrorMsg: %s\n", user.NewOK().ErrorMsg())
}
```

This will print the following:

```
Using %s: [Error] Email required!
Using %v: [Error] Email required!
Using %v and call function ErrorMsg: [Error] Email required!
Using %s and call function ErrorMsg: [Error] Email required!
```

However without `error` interface:

```
type NewUser struct {
    Email    string
    Password string
}

type ResponseError interface {
    ErrorMsg() string
}

type CustomErr string

func (c CustomErr) ErrorMsg() string {
    return "[Error] " + string(c)
}


func (u *NewUser) NewOK() ResponseError {
    if len(u.Email) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Email required!")
    }
    if len(u.Password) == 0 {
        return CustomErr("Password Required!")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    user := NewUser{}
    fmt.Printf("Using %%s: %s\n", user.NewOK())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%v: %v\n", user.NewOK())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%v and call function ErrorMsg: %v\n", user.NewOK().ErrorMsg())
    fmt.Printf("Using %%s and call function ErrorMsg: %s\n", user.NewOK().ErrorMsg())
}
```

The output is :

```
Using %s: Email required!
Using %v: Email required!
Using %v and call function ErrorMsg: [Error] Email required!
Using %s and call function ErrorMsg: [Error] Email required!
```